# phpunit: using host root based paths

Tags: php, path, phpunit, require

I installed phpunit as a PHar:

1. Downloaded the PHar file from wget http://pear.phpunit.de/get/phpunit.phar
2. Saved it in (/usr/share/phpunit).
3. Made it executable (`chmod +x phpunit.phar`).
4. Created a link to it in /usr/bin.

Now I can call it, but I have to define the path to the tested class in the require call either relativ from the directory, where I'm calling phpunit from (s. example 1), or absolutely from root (s. example 2).

example 1 (file /var/www/sandbox/phpunit/tests/FooTest.php)

```
<?php
require_once('../Foo.php');

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testBar() {
        $input = 5;
        $this->assertEquals(5, (new Foo())->bar());
    }
}
```

example 2 (file /var/www/sandbox/phpunit/tests/FooTest.php)

```
<?php
require_once('/var/www/sandbox/phpunit/Foo.php');

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testBar() {
        $input = 5;
        $this->assertEquals(5, (new Foo())->bar());
    }
}
```

What do i need to configure (and how) in order to be able to use host root based paths? E.g., if /var/www/sandbox/phpunit/ is the root folder of my website:

```
<?php
require_once('/Foo.php');

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testBar() {
        $input = 5;
        $this->assertEquals(5, (new Foo())->bar(5));
    }
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reply!

I've resoved it with Arne Blankerts' [Autoload / phpab](https://github.com/theseer/Autoload). It calls the `spl_autoload_register` function with a closure as first argument and defines in this anonymous function a generated array of the classnames and their files (with elements like 'myclass' => '/path/to/MyClass.php'). I've included the generated file to my phpunit bootstrap.php. And now it's working. :)

```
# phpab -o autoload.inc.php .
```

My file structure:

```
/qwer
/qwer/Foo.php
/tets
/tets/FooTest.php
/tets/phpunit.xml
/autoload.inc.php
/bootstrap.php
```

/qwer/Foo.php

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function bar($input) {
        return $input;
    }
}
```

/tets/FooTest.php

```
<?php
class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testBar() {
        $input = 5;
        $this->assertEquals(5, (new Foo())->bar(5));
    }
}
```

/tets/phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit bootstrap="../bootstrap.php" colors="true">
</phpunit>
```

/autoload.inc.php

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
// @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
// this is an autogenerated file - do not edit
spl_autoload_register(
    function($class) {
        static $classes = null;
        if ($classes === null) {
            $classes = array(
                'foo' => '/qwer/Foo.php',
                'footest' => '/tests/FooTest.php'
            );
        }
        $cn = strtolower($class);
        if (isset($classes[$cn])) {
            require __DIR__ . $classes[$cn];
        }
    }
);
// @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
```

/bootstrap.php

```
<?php
require_once 'autoload.inc.php';
```

EDIT:

A disadvantage of this approach is, that I have to start phpab every time after creating a new class. OK, for small test projects a combination of two commandos can be used:

```
# phpab -o ../autoload.inc.php .. && phpunit .
```

Or the same with an alias like `myprojectphpunit`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you won't be able to reference the web root if you're not running the program via the web. That much is fairly obviousl.

The best solutions I can think of would be either to have the web root hard coded as a variable or constant into the phpunit config or bootstrap file, or use the magic constant `__DIR__` to reference files relative to the current file.

I tend to use the latter anyway, even when I am loading via the web, as it allows my code to be hosted from subdirectory, without be worrying about where the web root is.